# No success message when updating/go back to the list grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm using Codeigniter and Grocery Crud for a project The crud is working fine but the problem is that when I add the text-editor then i don't get the success message ..
here when i am adding this line

```
  $crud->change_field_type('description', 'text');
```

add and update doesn't show the success message but if i remove this and use simple input box then i get the message successfully.

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

I did your example:

Controller:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();


            //$crud->set_theme('datatables');
            $crud->set_table('text');
            $crud->required_fields('description');
            $crud->columns('description');
            $crud->fields('description');
            $crud->display_as('id','No')
                ->display_as('description','Description');

            $output = $crud->render();

            $this->_example_output($output);
```

**Don't forget to set datatype of description "text" in DB.**

It works!

Comment: i have changed the datatype varchar to "text" in db ..but mine still didnt work ... success message not coming up

Comment: What version of grocery CRUD are you using ?

Comment: latest .recently around two or three weeks earlier i have downloaded